# How organize classes for MVC

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to organize my classes responsible for View, i have main GUI class MyWindow which have few sub-classes which have own sub-classes (all the classes/sub-classes are in separate files), then i have Controller class, and one class Module PerformDownload.

For now each class create own instances of subclasses. Let say it look like that:

> --- Controller
>
> --------- PerformDownload
>
> --------- MyWindow
>
> --------------- Container
>
> ------------------------ OuterPanel
>
> ------------------------ InnerPanel
>
> --------------- Panel

MyWindow create object Container which create own object OuterPanel which create own InnerPanel and at this point using Observer pattern i want to send date from InnerPanel to PerformDownload.

My solution that i see for it is to create all View object directly in Controller class, it would solve my communication problems but I'm wondering if it would not infringe one of the Object Oriented rules like encapsulation.

Comment: What's important is that you are comfortable and consistent. I've seen solutions that have a "group" in directory, the controller at the top level, then the view and model separated into sub directories, I've also heard of developers wanting to kill the person who came up with the idea

Comment: I know that there is a lot of solutions and all of them would work here but i want to know which one is the best. I'm on learning stage and i don't want to fall into some patterns that would work now, but stop working when code start to be more complicated

Comment: Which one is the "best" is debatable and every one will have their own opinion